# Ajax/jquery how to send data from button click without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

ive been trying for hours to get this to work and havent moved a budge.

What im trying to do is send an url when a button is click, but without refreshing the page

php code of button:

```
    echo '<a href="#" class="approve-button" id="'.$link_url[link_url].'">Send</a>';
```

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Attach an onclick handler to each of your buttons that are meant to "approve"
$('approve-button').click(function(){

   //Get the ID of the button that was clicked on
   var id_of_item_to_approve = $(this).attr("id");


   $.ajax({
      url: "votehandler.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
      type: "POST",
      data: "id=" + id_of_item_to_approve, //The data your sending to some-page.php
      success: function(){
          console.log("AJAX request was successfull");
      },
      error:function(){
          console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
      }   
    });

});

</script>
```

votehandler.php:

```
<?php

    $data = $_POST['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `link` SET `up_vote` = up_vote +1 WHERE `link_url` = '$data'");

?>
```

Ive removed all the error checks from votehandler.php to try to get any response but so far nothing.

any advice is welcome, trying to understand jquery/ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

- The jquery selector isn't working. Correct is: `'a[class="approve-button"]'`
- The code should being wrapped within the jquery [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to make sure that the DOM (with the links) has already been loaded before the javascript code executes.

Here comes a working example:

```
$(function() { // wrap inside the jquery ready() function

//Attach an onclick handler to each of your buttons that are meant to "approve"
$('a[class="approve-button"]').click(function(){

   //Get the ID of the button that was clicked on
   var id_of_item_to_approve = $(this).attr("id");


   $.ajax({
      url: "votehandler.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
      type: "POST",
      data: "id=" + id_of_item_to_approve, //The data your sending to some-page.php
      success: function(){
          console.log("AJAX request was successfull");
      },
      error:function(){
          console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
      }   
    });

});

});
```